# Starting off in node.js getting errors Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined, and Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am just starting off in Node.js and trying to use modules. I have node and npm installed and made sure everything is good to go. I will put the code bellow to show you what I am getting.

I have two files of js and here they are.

app.js:

```
var movies = require('./movies');
movies.avatar();
```

movies.js:

```
function printAvatar(){
  console.log("avatar pg-13");
}

function printChappie(){
  console.log("chappie pg-13");
}

module.exports.avatar = printAvatar;
```

Here is the html page I am running it on so I can see the console:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="movies.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

So basically when I run this I should be printing to the console "avatar pg-13". Except that is not happening. Here are the two errors I have received in the console.

Error1: Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined              movie.js:9

Error2: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined             app.js:1

Comment: You're running Node.js code in the browser, I think that you can use browserify to make it work in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot run node code through HTML without using nw.js or similar. Open the command prompt, navigate to the folder where your code is, and type `node app.js`.

You could perhaps use browserify to make it runnable in the browser, but not all node code can be browserified.

Comment: I did the command prompt and got Error: Cannot find module 'c:\Users\Amazo\Node.js\Taylor\apps.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:963:3

Comment: Also I am using atom and have a package that allows me to have a console in atom. And I get this error: Run in Atom Error: Error: Cannot find module './movies'(…)

Comment: You typed `apps.js`, with an s.

Comment: That is embarrassing haha thank you so much, do you know of a text editor that is free that is good for node js?

Comment: You can use any decent text editor that has syntax highlighting and auto indent. Notepad++ seems to be popular, but Atom is also great.

Comment: If it helped, I'd appreciate if you accepted the answer. Notepad++ is a good choice for a basic text editor. If you're a student you can get WebStorm for free, which has excellent Node support.

Comment: It was making me wait a certain time to put this as the answer sorry about that and I know about Notepad++ I just didnt want to have to go to a separate terminal each time I had to type node ~ something~ thanks for the help!

Comment: There's an NppExec plugin that allows you to run stuff directly in NP++.

Comment: Thanks so much found and using now, also I happen to be a student so I get a free year of webstorm. You have helped very much!

Answer (score -1):

you can use `require` on browser, let try browserify, or run your code with `node` command on terminal

Comment: When I ran in the terminal with: node app.js I got Error: Cannot find module 'c:\Users\Amazo\Node.js\Taylor\apps.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:963:3

Comment: Also I am using atom and have a package that allows me to have a console in atom. And I get this error: Run in Atom Error: Error: Cannot find module './movies'(…)